# can Anyone help me to connect my application to Access

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc

Here's the connect code

```
public class Connect {
    public ResultSet rs;
    Statement st;
    Connection con;
    PreparedStatement pStat;
    ResultSetMetaData rsm;

    public Connect() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        try {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            File tempFile = new File("Project.mdb");
            con = DriverManager
                    .getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=" + tempFile.getAbsolutePath());
            st = con.createStatement(1004, 1008);
            System.out.println("CONNECT");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Error Connection");
        }
    }

    public ResultSet executeQuery(String query) 
    {
        try {
            rs = st.executeQuery(query);
            rsm = rs.getMetaData();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Error Connection RS");
        }
        return rs;
    }
```

and here's the error

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLDriverConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcConnection.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)`enter code here`
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    enter code here
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20755393/how-to-connect-ms-access-through-java-and-how-to-configure-odbc-driver-in-window

Comment: You might also be interested in [Manipulating an Access database from Java without ODBC](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21955256/2144390).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try to check if you can access that database via ODBC.
2. Make `DSN` in `odbcad32` for both 64 and 32 bit systems.
3. Then as JDBC connect string use: jdbc:odbc:[CreatedDSN]. If you cannot connect to Access in 64 bit version of odbcad32 then make sure it works in 32 bit version of odbcad32 and make sure you use 32 bit version of Java.

For more info go to [link](http://www.selikoff.net/2011/07/26/connecting-to-ms-access-file-via-jdbc-in-64-bit-java/)